# Почему знаки присуждаются так поздно?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки

Почему при выполнении действия за которое присуждается какой-либо знак, знак может присудиться через несколько часов, а может и больше? Это вряд ли связано с загруженностью сайта.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Присуждение знаков осуществляется набором периодически запускающихся заданий с разным интервалом, от нескольких минут до суток. В результате, некоторые знаки присуждаются почти сразу, а другие нужно ждать. Сроки для конкретных знаков не определены, но не превышают 24 часа (наибольший интервал имеют знаки за метки, которые пересчитываются раз в день).

Источник: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/370389